# Get the parentNode of checked checkbox items

Tags: javascript

Hoe I am trying to use querySelectorAll to select all parent items which have their child checkbox checked.

Basically the HTML is

```
<div id=""><input type="checkbox" value="test"></div>
```

I want to select all the divs which have their input checkbox checked, so here is my javascript code

```
var list = querySelectorAll("input:checked.parentNode.getAttribute('id')");
```

but when i checked the list.length it returns 0, althought there are some checkbox have been checked, but

```
var list = querySelectorAll("input:checked");
```

this works fine. But I want an array of the parent items.

Could someone help me with it, and tell me why my original code does not work?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `parentNode` is not useable as a CSS selector, I suggest you do like this

```
  var list = querySelectorAll("input:checked");
  var parentlist = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    parentlist.push(list[i].parentNode.id);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.parentNode` will work if you will get the list of `input:checked` and access the `parentNode`. `parentNode` is not defined in CSS.

Use this:

```
list= querySelectorAll('div>input:checked")
```

This will select all the `div` elements with `input:checked`.

See more here:
[CSS Selectors Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

the problem you have is that

```
document.querySelectorAll("input:checked");
```

returns an array of elements, so the selector

```
var list = querySelectorAll("input:checked.parentNode.getAttribute('id')");
```

is invalid, you are trying to execute "parentNode" in an array

you should first get the checked elements (`document.querySelectorAll("input:checked");` ) and then do a foreach loop on it to get the parent node and the id.

hope this helps